# R object in function not found

Tags: r, function, object, replicate

I have a problem with a function after I commented it out and again in. It worked before, but now I cannot find what's causing the problem.

Data to reproduce:

```
xmat <- matrix(rexp(200, rate=.1), ncol=20)
ymat <- matrix(rexp(10, rate=.1), ncol=1)
```

package used:

```
if ( !("ensr" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) || (packageVersion("ensr") < "0.1.0.9001" ) ) {
  remotes::install_github('dewittpe/ensr')
}
```

Code:

```
set.seed(2020)

nboot = 1000

bootstraps <- replicate(nboot, {ws <- sample(1:nrow(xmat), replace = TRUE); 
  ensr(xmat[ws, ], ymat[ws, ], standardized = FALSE, family="gaussian", nlambda=100, nfolds=10,
alpha=c(0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0)
)}, 
simplify = FALSE)
```

I get the error that the object "ws" cannot be found. If I create it outside the function it is no problem, but I need it inside, to have it in every bootstrap.
Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Try adding one more argument in your function call: `ensr(<your original arguments>, envir = environment())`.

Comment: Thanks ekoam, unfortunately it is still not working...

Comment: Hi @Linda, I can't reproduce your problem. Your code works with/without this argument added `envir = environment()`. I think that you need to either reinstall that package or restart Rstudio.

Comment: Hey @ekoam, thanks so much, you were right. It was really a session or package problem. It works now with a fresh session and the re-loaded package...